# Why aren't my negative matches working?

Tags: ssh, openssh

The following entry in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` works like a charm:

```
Match User andreas
    ForceCommand /bin/echo "You are Andreas"
```

However, if I try to replace it with a negative match, it does not catch the user `andreas` at all:

```
Match User !bob
    ForceCommand /bin/echo "You are not Bob"
```

There are no error messages or anything, it just continues on as if the config option was never set.

[According to the man pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5), negative patterns should work:

> The arguments to `Match` are one or more criteria-pattern pairs or the single token All which matches all criteria. The available criteria are `User`, `Group`, `Host`, `LocalAddress`, `LocalPort`, and `Address`. The match patterns may consist of single entries or comma-separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation operators described in the [**PATTERNS**](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5#x5041545445524e53) section of `ssh_config(5)`.

Comment: have you tried putting double quotes around the !user

Comment: @Schwertspize Just tried it, still no result (and yes, I restarted `sshd` after making any changes to the config file).

Answer (score 8):

I found [this related post on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/44707/how-to-restrict-everyone-except-a-certain-group-in-ssh/44868#44868).

This is a weird behaviour but you might try:

```
Match User *,!bob
    ForceCommand /bin/echo "You are not Bob"
```

Quoting [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/289073):

> To use negation in Match conditional blocks, the expression needs to be preceded by a `*`.
>   For instance, given the following section in the bottom of `sshd_config`:
>   Raw
>
> ```
> Match Group *,!admin Address 192.168.1.1
>     ForceCommand /bin/false
> ```
>
> This would deny connections from *192.168.1.1* to anyone who is not in the *admin* group. The connection denial is achieved using the `ForceCommand` statement which instructs the sshd server to run a dummy command (`/bin/false`) and exit immediately.
>
> #### Root Cause
>
> The cause of this non-intuitive behaviour is dependent on the implementation of negation in OpenSSH.
>
> Ref. https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1315

Comment: This was so helpful. After wasting hours of reading logs finally it worked.

Comment: The reason this is necessary (as described under PATTERNS of ssh_config(5)) is because "a negated match will never produce a positive result by itself."  That's fine where most PATTERNS may be used, but it's weird with a Match block.

Answer (score 1):

negative matches are unfortunately broken and will be hopefully fixed in openssh-7.0:

See these bugs:

- https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2397
- https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1918

Comment: Unfortunately, negative matches are still not working in `OpenSSH_7.4p1`

Comment: Yes, there were some issues how to do it properly. See the last comments in the bug https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1918 -- in OpenSSH 7.6 should come with (hopefully) final state.